# how can I fix 'Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaNNaN"

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

It keep me showing this error everytime rendering the star and end date. I already tried give date format long but still error shows...

> ```
> start: Date.UTC(2019, 02, 30), // this line is error
>  end: Date.UTC(2019, 08, 23), // this line is error
>
>  Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".
>  Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".
>  Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaNNaN".
>  Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaNNaN".
> ```

I just need to render it but it shows that these start and end are in 
 wrong format or shows error.
 This is the jsfiddle : [Online example](https://jsfiddle.net/L90zchmp/)

```
 var today = new Date(),
        day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;    
    var options = {
        title: {
            text: 'Visual Planner Chart with Navigation',
        },
        xAxis: 
            currentDateIndicator: true,
            min: today - 3 * day,
            max: today + 18 * day
        },
        yAxis: {
            uniqueNames: true

        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Visual Planner',
            data: [],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.owner}'
            }
        }]
    }    


 // for reference https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/
 var ganttChart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container-ganttChart', options)    

 // call gantt chart then add series
 ganttChart.series[0].addPoint({
   start: Date.UTC(2019, 01, 30),
   end: Date.UTC(2019, 05, 29),
   name: 'crewRank',
   owner: 'crewName'
 })
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I cant give the data since the data from API

Comment: You can use example data.

Comment: hi friend, please see this sample https://jsfiddle.net/g6n308v9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getTime` method to get milliseconds and then use them in calculations:

```
var today = new Date().getTime(),
    day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

Additionally, change value in `selected` property:

```
rangeSelector: {
    ...,
    selected: 1
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mbyn8k0d/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.selected